# getnameinfo with boost asio

Tags: c++, boost

```
 void mycode()
 {
     struct sockaddr_in saGNI;
     char servInfo[NI_MAXSERV];

     WSADATA   wsadata;
     if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsadata) != 0) {
         //printf("WSAStartup failed: %d\n", statuswsadata);
     }

     saGNI.sin_family = AF_INET;
     saGNI.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("10.80.101.162");
     saGNI.sin_port = htons(64);

     char host[512]; // <-- information to obtain
     getnameinfo((struct sockaddr *) &saGNI, sizeof(struct sockaddr), host, NI_MAXHOST, servInfo, NI_MAXSERV, NI_NUMERICSERV);
 }
```

I would like to get a hostname with an IP as input. The above code do that, but I will prefer to do it with Boost asio, is it possible ?

Comment: `boost::asio` would be your best bet. I know that it can resolve a name to an IP address, but I don't know whether it supports `getnameinfo`.